# What browser feature is this exploiting and how to stop it?

Tags: security, javascript, firefox, exploit

http://raffa991[dot]ra[dot]funpic[dot]de/lol/
***Warning: It is some kind of an annoying "you are an idiot" sign combined with a lot of popup message boxes. Open with care!***

In any case, it crashed my firefox 3.5.4. (or to be more precise, made it unusable) ... I don't know about other browsers.

Since it's been a while since something that stupid did something like that, I'm wondering ... what weakness is that thing using (Javascript ?), and how to protect oneself from it ?

Comment: @Nifle - what was the point of that edit ? I don't mind, I just think it was more clear the way it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the page source (using a text-mode downloader), it seems it is mostly Javascript.

The best way to avoid these kinds of annoyances is to use [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/722).

It also seems to have a Flash object somewhere in the page. [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/433) can help with that.

There is also some code which moves windows all over the screen. Firefox has a preference which allows you to disable moving and resizing windows (`dom.disable_window_move_resize`); you should enable it (you do not need to use about:config for it, it is somewhere in the preferences dialog). While at that, also disable blocking the context menu (`dom.event.contextmenu.enabled`); it is in the same place in the preferences dialog.

Finally, the relevant bug report is [Bug 61098 – Exit all currently active scripts (allow aborting modal window.alert() loops in javascript (js))](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61098) (warning: over 200 comments on that bug report). Finding a solution to bug 61098 (and coding it) will be a large step on avoiding this problem.

**Edit:** an even better bug report is [bug 432687](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/showdependencytree.cgi?id=432687&hide_resolved=1), which is the meta-bug tracking all bug reports relevant to this problem.

Comment: NoScript deals with flash as well.

Comment: The flash object is the sound. NoScript blocks flash objects by default.

Comment: Beat by 31 seconds!

Comment: @John T: not if you temporarily allow Javascript on a page. When you do that, Flashblock takes over.

Answer (score 3):

I cURL'ed the page and put it up (raw text, no worries) [on pastebin.ca](http://pastebin.ca/1848216).

I also deleted ~400 blank lines that started off the page.

It looks to be pure javascript, switching between several arrays to make the title move and the text change.

[NoScript](http://noscript.net/) soundly defeats this. It won't however defeat stuff like http://tinyurl.com/y8qdwsv without some ahead thinking.

**Warning. Clicking that link can be hazardous to your computer's health.**

Comment: The problem with that tinyurl link is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167475 (it uses several IFRAMEs with SRC="mailto:...")

Comment: Correct, however it's still not fixed. 3.6 is vulnerable to this along with al the major browsers I've tested it in. It would also be a pain if you injected a <iframe src="http://path/to/page" /> into an include file in a site, thus making every page an attack page. Not sure how you would do that but I think it's a decently sized problem.

Comment: The pastebin died.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail So did the tinyurl. It's been a while :)

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's javascript alright. Check out the [**NoScript**](http://noscript.net/) extension, it's great for blocking annoying things like this.

Answer (score 2):

Just a regular old JavaScript prank site, it looks like. (Pointed cURL at the address :P)

As you're using Firefox, you can disable the window movement in `Preferences ->Content ->Javascript ->Advanced`, though there's no way to stop the messagebox spam built in, you could use NoScript to kill it before it has a chance to run.